# Get log of AdSense ads showed on my website

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

Is there a way to get a report of the ads that have been shown to the visitors of my website? Not just number of ads and clicks, but actual content of the ads.

Comment: Simple answer. No! That would be giving away the store!

Comment: @closetnoc Why? It's not like I would host it myself for free... I'd just like to know which ads are served to my visitors

Comment: Because the ad network would be giving away their stock and trade. It is their proprietary business to safe guard their customer base and methods. If they gave you and anyone else a list, they would be divulging secrets that would allow someone to reverse engineer their proprietary processes and customer base for anyone to steal.

Answer (score 2):

@**closetnoc** is correct, there isn't such log available to us (publishers).

www.google.com/adsense > Allow & block ads > Ad review center is probably all you need.

What the progress bar in the Ad review center shows
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6006756

Report of the ads that have been shown to the visitors of your website could be a very, very long list and you could even find it is not very useful / interesting / is boring.

Comment: I keep asking for this feature.   I feel I have a right to know what is being advertised on my site.   I'd like too see which ads are shown most often at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Adsense Sandbox](http://ctrlq.org/sandbox/) which gives you better result than galeksic answer(Don't mind it bro :) ).